# noun clause or adverb clause

Tags: grammar

### I read on Google books and exactly on this book:
Applications of Grammar: Analysis of Effective Communication, Book 3
By Garry J. Moes, Ed Shewan

The following

Adverb clauses page 141

It is clear [that you do not know the facts]. (clause modifies the adjective "clear"
So, as a clause or any item grammar can qualify ( adjective ) = that item ( modifier ) no doubt = adverb

Others would say the clause ( that you do not know the facts) = noun clause appositive of the impersonal pronoun ( it )

**( that you do not know the facts ) Is it noun clause or adverb clause ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *It is clear* [*that you do not know the facts*].

The subordinate clause "that you do not know the facts" is neither a modifier not an appositive, but a declarative content clause.

The sentence is an extraposition construction with the dummy pronoun "it" as subject and the subordinate (*that*) clause as extraposed subject. The predicative complement of "be" is just "clear", just as it is in the non-extraposed "That you do not know the facts is clear".

Incidentally, I would suggest that you avoid the terms 'noun clause' and 'adverb clause'. Noun and adjective are parts of speech, not clause types.

Comment: Thank you @https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/31780/billj   So, it is a noun clause , isn't it ?

Comment: @AhmadMohammad **No!** As I said, it's a declarative content clause functioning as an extraposed subject. My advice to you is to get rid of that book; its analyses are wrong.